# Clearing lines from file, issue with sed on ZSH

Tags: macos, zsh

I am trying to clean files that contain references.
If the asset is gone then the reference should be forgotten.

I use this to delete every empty line. It works.

```
sed -i '' '/^$/d' $reffile
```

Now I try to use this below to delete every line that contains the string in $mystring. It doesn't work. The dual single quote after the -i is supposed to be macOS specific I read somewhere. Also that sed has different ways on different platforms.

```
sed -i '' '/$mystring/d' $reffile
```

So I ended up using grep instead

```
grep -v $mystring $reffile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile $reffile
```

But still curious about sed and why I could not make it work. I'd love to know more.

Comment: _I'd love to know more._ : You find this in the section `QUOTING` in man zshmisc: _Inside **double** quotes (""), parameter and command substitution occur_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use double quotes instead, check this out :

```
sed -i "" "/$mystring/d" $reffile
```

but if you prefer to use single quotes and still want to include the variable, it's better to concatenate the variable outside the quotes like below :

```
sed -i '' '/'"$mystring"'/d' $reffile
```

good luck !

Comment: The first with double quotes doesn't work on my system.
The second solution works. I did miss the concatenation! Thank you.

Comment: To remove lines
is sed better than grep > mv
?

Comment: @Greg well,If you only need to remove lines that match a simple pattern, using `grep -v` and moving the result to the original file with `mv` can be a straightforward and efficient solution. and `grep` is generally faster than `sed` for simple pattern matching tasks,`grep` is specifically optimized for searching patterns in files and can handle large files more efficiently.

Comment: yes i ended up using grep as in my original post. Thank you for clarifying the difference though. Good choice. For the sed command to remove empty lines, it works but would it be better with grep also? How would you do that?

Comment: sure, something like this : `grep -v "$mystring" "$reffile" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$reffile"`